# Why $E[X|\mathcal{G}]=X$ if $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

If $X$ is a $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable, why $E[X|\mathcal{G}] = X$? I know the intuition (basicly we're conditioning on the same informations on which $X$ is defined, $\sigma(X)$, we can't gain any different information), but I don't know how to prove it rigourously

Answer (score 6):

To show $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ equals some $Y$. You need to check:

1. $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable;
2. $\int_A Y(\omega)dP(\omega)=\int_A X(\omega)dP(\omega)$ for all $A\in\mathcal{G}$.

In this case, the claim is $Y=X$ works. (1) holds by assumption and (2) holds trivially.

Comment: and for $X$ being independent of $\mathcal{G}$ are we using a similar argument to get $E[X]$?

Comment: $E[X]$ is nonrandom so it is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable. To prove the second property, one way to do it is with the "standard machine": consider these cases successively (i) $X$ is an indicator function, (ii) $X$ is a non-negative simple function, (iii) $X$ is a non-negative measurable function, (iv) $X$ is a general measurable function. (i) usually is just definition, (ii) uses (i) and linearity, (iii) uses (ii) and Dominated Convergence, and (iv) is (iii) plus definition.

Comment: @KimJongUn you also need to show that $E(|Y|) < \infty$ in your list of properties, right?